# CPU usage 100 % when compile google map

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-studio, cpu

When I compile Android Studio when I say that my application is Google Play The following error occurs.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException:
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException:
>   org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException:
>   Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_51\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Comment: Error:The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Comment: This has nothing to do with CPU usage. You **want** CPU usage to be at 100% when compiling--that literally means that the computer is doing the work you asked for.

Comment: Can you post your build.gradle file?

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpWxu.png

Answer (score 0):

You are depending on the whole Google Play Services. As stated in [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup):

> If the number of method references in your app exceeds the 65K limit, your app may fail to compile. You may be able to mitigate this problem when compiling your app by specifying only the specific Google Play services APIs your app uses, instead of all of them.

So, if you are only using Google Maps in your project, you can use this dependency (this example uses the last vesion of Google Play Services)

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.6.1'
}
```

instead of

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.6.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, avoid using of `+` while compiling library.

And instead of adding the entire google play services, only add what you required.

In your case, instead of adding

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.3.+'
```

download latest google repository and add

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:9.8.0'
```